# Phonegap ios certificate issue with push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create ios app using phone gap with push notification functionality. I am able to create certificate but those certificate doesn't register my device and without registering device push notification functionality can not be achieved. Can any one tell me the steps to generate correct certificates i.e. certificate.p12 file and mobile provisioning profile file which are required to generate ipa file on PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

I am following these steps to create certificate(p12 file and provisioning file).

Create App in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

Go to certificate menu and create new https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/
Requesting a new certificate

Open the keychain on your computer.
From the menu you select "Certificate assitant" and choose "Request a certificate from a Certificate Authority (...)".

Enter your Apple-ID email adress and click on "Save to disk". Also check the checkbox below, saying something about setting the keys to use.

You should be prompted for a passphrase for your freshly made keys. Enter something and write it down somewhere.

Upload your Certificate Request file (you created above) and wait until the certificate is issued (may take a few minutes, refresh the site a few times).
If your certificate shows as issued, download it.

Now click on the "Provisioning" section.
You can either create a new provisioning profile or edit an existing one.
Make sure to have your certificate enabled in the profile you're going to use.

Now you have a .mobileprovision file and a certificate (.cer) - there is still one missing: The certificate/key bundle (*.p12) - let's create it!

Open the keychain tool on your computer.
Import the certificate by selecting "File" > "Import object" from the menu.

The certificate should now show up below the key you used to request the certificate.
Right-click on your key and select "Export".